# messages from a remote queue to another remote queue

Tags: ibm-mq

We have 2 MQ Queue Managers, and one WAS server. We need to send message from QM01 to QM02 and then from QM02 to WAS server.

For doing this we have built a sender channel between QM01 and QM02, message is placed over a remote queue which has a definition of another remote queue for the WAS Service Integration Bus queue.

Is there any harm in sending message as following;

> Remote Queue on QM01 ==> Remote Queue on QM02 ==> Queue on SI
>   Bus on WAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid method of hopping messages from one queue manager to another, especially if the queue managers are not clustered.  There is no harm to the message or the environment with this approach, though it does has a little more administrative overhead as opposed to a cluster-based solution.

Comment: this is working fine, but in QM02 i am not performing any mediation over the messages just forwarding it to Queue on SI Bus to the WAS. So this approach is a valid one, right?